# HTML5 <video> won't play MP4 video

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, html5-video, mp4

On a Raspberry Pi Apache server I have a HTML file that includes this:

```
<div class="left_frame" id="left_frame">
    <video width="640" height="480" controls>
        <source src="test_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser doesn't support this.
    </video>
</div>
```

The video file plays fine with VLC, but when I load this page in Firefox, it says "No video with supported format and MIME type found" (with a sad document icon).

In Chrome, I just get a blank frame, with no message.

The video metadata show the codec as MPEG-4 Video. 640x480 @30fps. The "Decoded format" is given as Planar 4:2:0 YUV.

There's lots of old (often contradictory) stuff on the net about problems with Firefox and MP4, but (a) Mozilla's current documentation doesn't indicate any problems, and (b) that doesn't explain the situation with Chrome.

Additional question: I'm not currently doing it, but would it be possible (assuming I can get playback working) to play the video in a browser while it's also being recorded from a webcam attached to the server?

Comment: my guess will be specific encoding profile/level. Try using `ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level:v 4.1 -movflags faststart DestFile.mp4` If you are playing the video on the R-Pi you might need `profile:v main` or even `baseline` and a `-level:v 4.0` (would need to double-check what they support) (lower profile and levels will be better on older/slower hardware)

Comment: With such issues it is best to put the video so that others can access and inspect it. Also opening `chrome://media-internals` in a separate tab is a good way to troubleshoot what is going on.